# error when passing string argument from batch to vbs

Tags: string, batch-file, vbscript, arguments

I'm calling a vbs string with a batch file. I'm passing a string through batch to vbs.

Complete batch file:

```
C:
cd C:\folder
Set arg = "sample foo"
Wscript titi.vbs "%arg"
pause
```

But, when I read the argument into the VBScript with `str = Wscript.Arguments(0)` the value of `str` is `sample` and not to `sample foo`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a simple one and one which is commonly made by those having used other programming languages.

```bat
Set arg = "sample foo"
```

sets the variable: %arg<kbd>space</kbd>% to the string: <kbd>space</kbd>"sample foo"

---

The way to assign variables should be:

```bat
Set arg="sample foo"
```

or:

```bat
Set "arg="sample foo""
```

I prefer the latter.

BTW, you also missed a closing **`%`** when using `"%arg"` instead of `"%arg%"`.

Because you are using the argument as `"%arg%"` there is no neeed to set the double quotes into the actual variable string.

Just use:

```bat
CD /D "C:\folder"
Set "arg=sample foo"

Wscript titi.vbs "%arg%"

Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and working as expected,

1.vbs

```
str = Wscript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Echo(str)
```

1.bat

```
Wscript 1.vbs "sample foo"
```

cmd line output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The batch file you posted should have the VBScript output `arg` due to your malformed variable syntax. Even if you corrected `%arg` to `%arg%` you should get an empty string as output, because your variable assignment is malformed as well (`set arg =...` defines a variable `%arg %`).

Change

```
Set arg = "sample foo"
Wscript titi.vbs "%arg"
```

to

```
set "arg=sample foo"
Wscript titi.vbs "%arg%"
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: thanks, the solution works, sry for my newbie question